# From a file of different extensions in a directory, how to load a list of files by extension using \foreach latex command?

Tags: tikz-external, pgffor

Into of directory named by **dir**, I have the following files:

```
-> ./dir/fileA.eps
-> ./dir/fileB.eps
-> ./dir/fileC.eps
-> ./dir/filePNG-A.png
-> ./dir/filePNG-B.png
-> ./dir/filePNG-C.png
```

I would like to load only the *.eps files from **dir** and to put into the `\myfilelist` command as a list of these files, to execute a code similar to:

```
\newcommand{\myfilelist}{<*.eps file list>} % I don't know how to do it!!!

\foreach \file in \myfilelist 
{
  \tikzsetnextfilename{\file}   
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  {\includegraphics[]{\file}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

TeX has no access to operating system calls, such as the listing of a directory, unless we enable them via the `-shell-escape` option.

Here's my context:

```
> ls -R
subdir/     test.aux    test.log    test.pdf    test.tex

./subdir:
example-image-a.pdf example-image-b.pdf example-image-c.pdf
example-image-a.png example-image-b.png example-image-c.png
```

Here's the LaTeX file to be compiled with the `-shell-escape` option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile,tikz}

\newcommand{\getdir}[2]{\CatchFileDef#1{|"#2"}{\endlinechar=-1 }}

\begin{document}

\getdir{\myfilelist}{ls -m ./subdir/*.pdf}

\foreach\file in\myfilelist{
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{\file}\par
}

\end{document}
```

The graphics files are standard dummy images. Here's the output

[image]

You need to add the correct shell command call. On Unix, `ls -m` will return the items separated by commas.

---

An OS independent version using `kpsewhich`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getdir}{mm}
 {
  \adriano_getdir:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adriano_getdir:Nn
 {
  \sys_shell_get:nnN { kpsewhich ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getdir{\myfilelist}{./subdir/*.pdf}

\foreach\file in\myfilelist{
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{\file}\par
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And if it will be the Windows case, which is the command that would have replacing by `ls` command?

Comment: @Adriano Sorry, I keep as far from Windows as I can.

Comment: @Adriano I added a system independent version

Comment: I tested the your kpsewhich solution in Windows with Miktex, but the result was a clean screen, without showing any figure, even it compiling with -shell-escape option.

Comment: is there any way to load a specific extension comma-separated file list, by processing a windows shell command into the latex command, and afterwards to put it into the latex new command?

Comment: I noted typing `dir \b *.eps > test.txt` inner of a eps figure directory, from windows shell, it has returned a `test.txt` file with a list of eps files, but they are not separated by commas. Does it help you to make other solution for the Windows case?

Answer (score 1):

With a (very) recent texlive you can list the files in a directory without using `--shell-escape` using the tool `l3sys-query` the package of the same name gives a document interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{l3sys-query}
\begin{document}

\QueryFiles{dir/*.eps}
{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{#1}\\
    \texttt{#1}
  \end{center}}


\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Including all eps files found, and giving their path.