# Import tex files from a folder with names respecting one simple apattern

Tags: import

Does someone know how to import several files from a folder with names respecting `dd-*.text` with `d` one decimal an * any kind of characters like ine teh following piece of code ?

```
\input{laws-of-time/01-fraisse.tex}

\input{laws-of-time/02-taylor.tex}

\input{laws-of-time/03-pareto.tex}

\input{laws-of-time/04-laborit.tex}

\input{laws-of-time/05-parkinson.tex}
```

I can do that in Python or even for fun in Bash but I am curious to see how to acheive this with (La)TeX.

Comment: TeX can only find files it knows the name of, unless you use Lua or shell escape.

Comment: As @PhelypeOleinik said, you can use shell escape. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499273/from-a-file-of-different-extensions-in-a-directory-how-to-load-a-list-of-files

Comment: this is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/compile-all-tex-files-within-a-folder-at-once/169186#169186 although that asks for all files rather than a wildcard match but issues are the same.

Comment: Thanks for all.